# Slow UICollectionView with asynchronous loading

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` which loads images of the iPad's memory and displays them in a grid,like Apple's Photos app. The `UICollectionViewCell` loads thumbnails asynchronously:

```
 func setImage(img:String){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            //load the image in the background
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img)
            //when done, assign it to the cell's UIImageView
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let imageView = self.imageView{
                    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img)
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

However, while scrolling the view lags as if it is waiting for the images to load, especially with Retina graphics. The cells and images are about 240x180px big. Is there anything wrong with the image loading above or further optimisations need to be made?

**UPDATE: Time profiler results**
[image]

Comment: Change your thread's priority from DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND OR DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, and see if your collection views performs better

Comment: I tried, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You've already found that you're loading the `UIImage` again on the main queue; fixing that will help.

`UIImage` lazy loads its internal image data in most cases.  One trick is to call its `CGImage` property while still on the background queue to force it to actually create its internal image data instead of lazily loading it when the image view is drawn the first time:

```
func setImage(img:String){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        //load the image in the background
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img)
        image.CGImage // <- Force UIImage to not lazy load the data
        //when done, assign it to the cell's UIImageView
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if let imageView = self.imageView {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        })
   })
}
```

***Note:** If you have a lot of images you may end up getting a memory warning fairly quickly doing this. If you do, this probably won't help because the memory warning will typically cause `UIImage` to clear its internal image data again to free up resources.*

Answer (score 1):

On the line

```
imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img)
```

I was loading the image again on the main thread, not the `image` loaded asynchronously. Changed to

```
imageView.image = image
```

Scrolling is a bit better, but yet choppy. The time profiler shows similar results as before. May the bottleneck be in the UIImageView drawing? It works fine with non-retina thumbnails.

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing =) Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck was that some thumbnails were scaled improperly and were a lot bigger than the UIImageView, which caused the longer loading time. I also presume this caused slower drawing since the UIImage had to be downscaled to fit in the UIImageView.

I fixed the thumbnail-generating code and scrolling is smooth again.

P.S. I also fixed the misplaced `UIImage(contentsOfFile: img)` variable in the initial code, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Swift:

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        let imagem = UIImage(named :"image")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.IMG_Novidades.image = imagem
        }
    }

    //THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the rasterize code does and how it improves performance?